# Java Regex Annotation and Requirement for HTTP body POST

Tags: java, regex, validation, post, annotations

I've just completed a project that returns a String from a POST method. The string returned is an "answer", and the POST BODY accepts a String "question".
My Object properties are as follows:

```
@NotNull(message = "Question can't be null.")
@NotEmpty(message = "Question must contain text.")
@Pattern(regexp = "\\?$",
        message = "Invalid question. Requires a question mark at the end.")
private String question;
private String answer;
```

The POSTMapping is as follows:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/answer")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public String getOneAnswer(@RequestBody @Valid String question) throws Exception {

    if(question.equals("")) {
        String missingInputErrorMessage = "question input is an empty or does not exist.";
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(missingInputErrorMessage);
    }

    int random = random.nextInt((10) + 1);
    for(Answers answer: seriesOfAnswers) {
        if(random == answer.getAnswerId()) {
            return answer.getAnswer().toString();
        }
    }

    return "Return this string if all else fails";
}
```

The BODY of the POSTS I've done are as follows:

```
{
"question": "This is a question"
}
```

and

```
{
"question": "This is a question?"
}
```

Currently regex doesn't validate whether there is a `?` at the end of the POST BODY or not. It just runs the answer regardless. If I change the input to an Object type, regex validates and and shows me the message regardless of whether there is a `?` or not. 
My question is this: If it's possible to use regex in this format, how do I get regex to properly validate that the "question" value, in the POST BODY, ends with a `?`?

**EDIT:**
Below, Emma mentioned my implementation might have been incorrect. She was right. Currently, there may be a better way to handle this, but while taking her advice, I decided not to use the @Pattern annotation, and instead have the regex call in the @PostMapping section.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/answer")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public String getOneAnswer(@RequestBody @Valid String question) throws Exception {

    // The string with the regex we'll need to use. "q" for question.
    String qMarkEndingRegex = "\\?$";
    // The pattern we're going to check.
    Pattern checkForQMark = Pattern.compile(qMarkEndingregex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
    // The matcher to actually check the question
    Matcher qMarkMatcher = checkForQMark.matcher(question);

    // if the matcher does NOT detect a question mark as the regex states, run this code.
    if (!qMarkMatcher.find()) {
        String needsQ = "You need to add a question mark at the end of your question.";
        return needsQ;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is just fine, it should work OK, maybe you're not correctly implementing it:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegularExpression{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "\\?\\s*$";
        final String string = "This is a question?\n"
             + "This is a question? ";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DUdaw8/1/)

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/DUdaw8/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/DUdaw8/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: Thanks for the video and the link. I was using Regex101 to review the syntax just to make sure I wrote it correctly. I think you might be right, the issue is probably that I'm not implementing it correctly. I'm going to test some options and see if something changes.

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you! I had to use the regex in the PostMapping, instead of in my Object property annotation. I appreciate it! (I'm unable to @ Emma for some reason)